# page not found error in drupal

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404

hi i am getting a strange error in my drupal website "Page not Found" when i click on Login page.I have no idea why this error is comes.
please let me know what may be the result.(this is error is only on two pages My Account Page and login page ,rest other pages are working fine).

Answer (score 2):

Things to try:

1. Rebuild the menues by loading admin/build/modules
2. Clear the cache via admin/settings/performance
3. Rebuilt permissions admin/content/node-settings

unless you have some kind of advanced setup (memcache, authcache, varnish, that kind of stuff) one of these should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where would say

*index.php was not found on this server*

and it turned out to be my .htaccess file was not configure to serve drupal from a subdirectory. Only the webroot.

This thread helped:

http://drupal.org/node/1585672?mode=2&sort=2

Basically I just had to edit RewriteBase on my .htaccess file to contain the value of my subdirectory.

So for example, if I'm serving drupal from here:

http://example.com/drupal/

Then I have to change the RewriteBase value in my `.htaccess` file to:

```
RewriteBase /drupal
```

Comment: This was the problem for me too. It seems the use of .htaccess is a pretty clumsy way to do this. It would make more sense to have all this in a virtual host configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, I'd like to clarify that I use localhost to support Drupal.

*racl101* actually give the proper answer. Here I present my specific solution based on what *racl101* gives us:

Go to .htaccess

```
sudo nano .htaccess
```

Find `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` (as my drupal url is `localhost/~MyName/drupal/` )

I uncomment `RewriteBase` and change it to `RewriteBase /~MyName/drupal/`

Then it works. *Good luck!*